# Отследить загрузку нескольких элементов (onload)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Такой вопрос, работаю с канвасом, нужно при загрузке изображений вызывать функцию, с одним изображением сделал без проблем.
     img.onload = function() {}

Но мне нужно отследить загрузку обеих изображений И ТОЛЬКО ТОГДА вызывать функцию, как это сделать? Вот что-то в этом плане:
     img.onload and img2.onload = function() {} но так не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
var counter = 2;

var myFunc = function() {
    // тут ваш код
};

var checkLoaded = function() {
    if (--counter == 0) {
        myFunc();
    }
};

img1.onload = checkLoaded;
img2.onload = checkLoaded;
```

Счётчик `counter` содержит количество изображений, которые должны быть загружены. Вы можете устанавливать этот счётчик программно (в зависимости от того, как вы хотите использовать этот код).

При загрузке очередного изображения счётчик уменьшается на 1 и делается проверка. Если значение счётчика равно 0, то вызывается функция `myFunc`. Там вы можете написать код, который должен выполняться после загрузки всех изображений.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант, без излишеств

```js
var countImages = 0;

var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg";
img1.onload = function(event) {
  countImages++;
  if(countImages == 2) onComplete();
};

var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy.jpg";
img2.onload = function(event) {
  countImages++;
  if(countImages == 2) onComplete();
};
function onComplete() {
   console.log("all loaded images");
   document.getElementById("i1").src = img1.src;
   document.getElementById("i2").src = img2.src;
};
```

```html
<img id="i1" src="" width="200" />
<img id="i2" src="" width="200" />
```